# attempting to get the number of followers from twitter api -- android

Tags: android, json, twitter

I am attempting to get the number of followers after making authentication in a json call to twitter api. The api call is successful but the challenge is how I can retrieve the number of followers from the json success call. Below is my attempt

```
private void getUserSettings(){
        try {
            consumer.setTokenWithSecret(ACCESS_KEY, ACCESS_SECRET);
            String a = consumer.sign(URL_GET_USER_SETTINGS);
            HttpGet get = new HttpGet(a);
            HttpClient c = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpResponse resp = c.execute(get);
            StatusLine statusLine = resp.getStatusLine();
              int statusCode = statusLine.getStatusCode();
              if (statusCode == 200) {
                JSONObject json = readJSONResponse(resp);
                twitterName = (String)json.get("screen_name");
              } else {
                Log.e(TAG, "Failed Get Twitter info");
              }
        }
```

please how can I get the number of followers from the below attempt

Comment: can you post the url, or the json response?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try

```
double amountOfFollowers = json.getDouble("followers_count");
```

Comment: **From review queue**: May I request you to please add some more context around your answer. Code-only answers are difficult to understand. It will help the asker and future readers both if you can add more information in your post.

Comment: @Juan Felippo please how can I get the latest twitter feed by an account and number of persons you are following